# sharedobjects multiple item

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6, shared-objects

Is there a way to store multiple items in a shared object? I want to store the score and it's profile name at the same time in an android game.

here is my code so far.

```
        if(playerScore > lvl1Score.data.score1 || lvl1Score.data.score1 == 0)
       {
           lvl1Score.data.score5 = lvl1Score.data.score4;
           lvl1Score.data.score4 = lvl1Score.data.score3;
           lvl1Score.data.score3 = lvl1Score.data.score2;
           lvl1Score.data.score2 = lvl1Score.data.score1;
           lvl1Score.data.score1 = playerScore;
           lvl1Score.data.scoreName1 = curUser;
           lvl1Score.flush();
       }

scoreBoard.one.text = String(lvl1Score.data.score1);
```

can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can store Objects in a shared object.

Following your example, this may look as follows:

```
lvl1Score.data.score5 = { score: 2, profileName: "some_score" };
```